# Interrupt sleep

Tags: objective-c

In this example a class inherits from NSThread. It executes methodA every 10 seconds, unless time is extended by method sleepFromBeginning:

```
- (void)main {
    while (!terminate) {
        sleep(10);
        [self methodA]
    }
}

- (void)sleepFromBeginning {
    // todo: Interrupt sleep and loop once more without calling methodA. How?
}
```

How is sleep interrupted without canceling its thread?

Comment: in methodA couldn't you add a conditional (example: if) statement to check something then run or not run depending on the outcome

Comment: Well, I want to extend the execution of methodA the duration of the sleep. I could decide to change the sleep time, according to when sleepFromBeginning was called, and then sleep for the desired time. What I'm after here is how to interrupt a sleeping thread, and make it running again.

Comment: Looks like CFRunLoop or NSCondition is a place to look.